# Error while trying to link two different math libraries with same symbols

Tags: c++, linux, namespaces, amd-processor, cmath

While linking the `cmath` and AMD math library to the C++, observing that the AMD math library replaces all the functions from `cmath`.

While debugging using GDB, found the following output which testifies the above statement.

commandline output from Gdb:
[image: commandline output from Gdb]

Attaching the code snippet which is used to check above statement.

```cpp
#include "amdlibm.h"
#include "math.h"

namespace amdfunc {
    void sqrttest() {
        printf("Calling amd func\n");
        double val = 22.34;
        double val1;
        double val2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000000; i++) {
            val1 = amd_sqrt(val);
        }
    }
}

namespace normalfunc {
    void sqrttest() {
        printf("Calling cmath func\n");
        double val = 22.34;
        double val1;
        double val2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000000; i++) {
            val1 = sqrt(val);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    normalfunc::sqrttest();
    amdfunc::sqrttest();
}
```

Command line: Used the following command to link the libraries and compile the code.

```bash
g++ test.cpp -g -o testinglib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include -I/home/test/include -Wl,-rpath,/home/test/lib /home/test/lib/libalm.so -lm
```

We reordered the libraries while compiling, observed the same error.
Attaching the AMD math library link from which we used the files https://www.amd.com/en/developer/aocl/libm.html

Compiling and running the executable

Comment: please include errors as text. Please do not use images for text

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 5000000000; i++)` -- What is the maximum value an integer can have?  What if `i` goes over this limit?  For a signed, 4 byte integer, it would be 2^32-1, and your 5000000000 is greater than this.

Comment: Currently main issue is regarding the invocation of two libraries. There are no hardcoded values. Just for running the code for awhile incremented loop with a huge value. Feel free to modify the values and can be tested with a much lower loop counts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behaviour

> AOCL-LibM is a C library you can
> link to your applications to replace the compiler provided math functions.

Documentation page 67

https://www.amd.com/content/dam/amd/en/documents/pdfs/developer/aocl/aocl-v4.0-ga-user-guide.pdf

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out. Is there any other way, we can achieve above requirement? We would like to use part of amd math library functions and part of cmath library functions. Thanks

Comment: @SaiKrishnaSirimisetty https://blog.habets.se/2012/05/Shared-libraries-diamond-problem.html

Comment: In the above reference, one approach was using default-symver option alone and other was defining a version-script files. But there are few limitations with these. With default-symver, it acts upon two versions of same library package, which is not the case in our scenario. Are there any alternate methods for achieving the goal? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modified the linker option with -Wl,-lm,-lalm, using

> -Wl

specifically it linked both libraries and while comparing observed that both libraries are getting used.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIcBP.png)